# Laravel 5 - encoding characters

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, html-entities, laravel-blade

In my language there is lot of special characters such as "š" or "č" and so on.

My problem is, that Laravel 5 is automatically encoding this characters. I already tried this methods :

{{ "šššččž" }} - Laravel will escape html and characters

{!! "šššččž" !!} - Laravel will not escape anything 
(I cannot use this one, because some user can put some tags into his username, and the html will not be escaped)

I do not want to use something like {!! htmlspecialchars.. !!}, i tried the shorter version, the laravel helper e(), but it will escape the characters as well.

So my question is, is there any option, to tell to Laravel to dont escape characters, or the only way how to do it is to use htmlspecialchars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way because Laravel uses [htmlentities()](https://php.net/htmlentities) function here and some national characters are changed here. For example in Polish `ó` letter is being change in source into `&oacute;` but of course it's being displayed as it should on page.

Comment: not good enough I need it gone. Decode is not working, I've tried htmlspecialchars_decode. Need it for javascript

Comment: http://laravel.io/forum/10-17-2014-laravel5-inject-json-into-blade-htmlentites-filter-applied-by-mistake?page=1